# How to use hooks in cucumber?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-junit, cucumber-java

I am new in cucumber framework. I'm automating login scenarios using cucumber with java. Following is my feature file -

[image]

And following is step definition file -

[image]

I wanted to execute `setUp()` methods once before all scenarios (methods implemented for the same) and `tearDown()` method after all scenarios. I've used cucumber `@Before` and `@After` hooks (may be not in correct way).

But I'm seeing same result as before not using these. It open 4 instances of browser for all four scenarios one by one and then do execute them. Is there any way to execute all these scenarios only with one browser instance (call `setUp()` method once for all scenarios)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    if (driver == null) {
       ...//What you have
    }
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
}
```

To start don't close the browser in the @After hook.

Comment: Cucumber creates a fresh instance of step definition and hook classes for each scenario. Thus the driver variable will always be null initially.

Comment: @Grasshopper I do this all the time. The last scenario in the feature file has tag @quit.  The `@After("`@quit") public void browser_quit() {driver.quit;}

Comment: The earlier comment was based on the fact that you had not mentioned static in the answer which you have clarified later on. For my knowledge how do you handle quitting the browser when scenarios are run from multiple feature files using tags as filters and only browser should remain open throughout?

Comment: Cucumber executes each scenario in a feature in the order they appear in that feature file, So Scenario 1 opens the browser and the last scenario explicitly closes it.  Our TeamCity is configured to run each feature file in parallel on 9 build servers so this works for us very well. Sorry about not mentioning static but you figured it out pretty quickly. :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a webdriver which is shared between scenarios and does not close until all the scenarios are run. You can do it by storing the webdriver instance in a static variable and adding a shutdown hook to the instance.

Have a look at this which gives you such a driver class -- [SharedWebDriver](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/examples/java-webbit-websockets-selenium/src/test/java/cucumber/examples/java/websockets/SharedDriver.java)

If you use it with a DI container such as PicoContainer you can inject the driver in the constructor. Else you can create an instance.

Also you should have a look at ScenarioOutline to condense the multiple login scenarios.